# Trouble with MKMapView zoom to annotation on load

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mkmapview

I'm having trouble zooming in on an annotation/pin when the MapView is loaded.

When loading the MapView, I want it to start zoomed out, and then zoom in toward the annotation/pin. The "animated" is set to "true". I'm not sure what it going wrong here.

When the map gets loaded, it briefly displays a gray screen with the pin and then the satellite map around it loads.

Thanks!

Using Swift 3

Map code:

```
   @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

   }



   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()


       let distanceSpan:CLLocationDegrees = 300
       let redRocks:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.665496, -105.205438)
       let redRocksPin = RedRocksPin(title: "Jerry Garcia 1/2/72", subtitle: "Red Rocks Amphitheatre", coordinate: redRocks)
       mapView.addAnnotation(redRocksPin)

       mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(redRocks, distanceSpan, distanceSpan), animated: true)
```

Pin Class:

```
import MapKit

class RedRocksPin: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
var title: String?
var subtitle: String?
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

init(title:String, subtitle:String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.title = title
    self.subtitle = subtitle
    self.coordinate = coordinate
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class declaration make these your class variables:

```
    let distanceSpan:CLLocationDegrees = 300
    let redRocks:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.665496, -105.205438)
```

In ViewWillAppear, do this:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(animted)
       view.layoutIfNeeded()

       let redRocksPin = RedRocksPin(title: "Jerry Garcia 1/2/72", subtitle: "Red Rocks Amphitheatre", coordinate: redRocks)
       mapView.addAnnotation(redRocksPin)
    }
```

And then this:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(redRocks, distanceSpan, distanceSpan), animated: true)
    }
```

So what this does is in your viewwillAppear, it will draw the mapView, so you are able to add the annotation without causing a crash, then in the viewdidappear, it will just zoom in on the annotation you added.

Not sure if this is the best way, but something to try.

Comment: Thank you for the response. For adding those lines into the class declaration, does that go where the IBOutlet is? Or after viewDidLoad? Also, I'm running into errors with adding the two "override" (Missing argument for parameter #1 in call) (Use of unresolved identifier 'redRocks'). The controller has UIKit and MapKit imported. Thanks!

Comment: Ok so for the super viewDidAppear & viewWillAppear, I will update them, i forgot to add the animated.

For the class declaration question, you put those after the brackets, after the class name. So above where the IBOutlet's are or below, depending on how you organize your code.

Comment: Still getting those same errors. `override func viewWillAppear() {` and `override func viewDidAppear() {`  are showing "Method does not override any method from its superclass".                                                    `super.viewDidAppear(animated)` and `uper.viewWillAppear(animated)` display "Use of unresolved identifier 'animated". Was there a misspelling with "animted" on the viewWillAppear in your code? Thanks.

Comment: Miles, i didn't add the code syntactically correct; not that you are in the wrong in this situation, but in the future try to take the code and add it in manually, rather than copying and pasting, this will prevent the problems that us lazy developers create :p I've edited the code to fix the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: Works now! Lesson learned, sorry about that! Thank you very much.